# Too many connections Mysql / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buen día,

Actualmente en la pagina que desarrolle a los usuarios les aparece este mensaje, busque y esto se debe a la cantidad máxima de peticiones permitidas por el servidor de MySQL, la base de datos esta alojada en un hosting el cual solo permite max_connections = 150 (para aumentar tengo que pasar a un hostin dedicado y no compartido), la verdad no se si estas son muy pocas o que las consultas que estoy haciendo están quedado abiertas.

Todas las consulta que realizo en la pagina es con esta función:

```
      protected function conectar (){
      $this->conexion=mysqli_connect(
          $this->servidor,
          $this->usuario,
          $this->password,
          $this->basededatos);

      if (!$this->conexion) {
          die("conexion erronea" . mysqli_connect_error());
      }
  }

  protected function desconectar (){
      mysqli_close($this->conexion);
  }

  public function ejecutar($query){
      $this->conectar();
      return mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
      $this->desconectar();
  }
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, ya se optimizando el código o recomendándome un hosting donde me permita hacer muchas mas conexiones

Comment: Estas creando una conexión por cada ejecución, mejor créala sólo si no hay una existente: `if( !isset($this->conexion) ) $this->conectar();`.

Answer (score 2):

Comentarios:

- El código actual que expones tiene el detalle que no cierra la conexión
- Lo anterior debido a que el llamado al método de cierre está ocurriendo después del [`return`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.return.php)

  - Aqui recomiendo del enlace leas en especial el segundo párrafo
- Ahora mas allá de eso, no alcanzaría con mover el return al final del código actual dejandolo de esta forma:

  ```
  public function ejecutar($query)
  {
      $this->conectar();
      $this->desconectar();
      return mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
  }
  ```

Ya que al menos a como lo veo, no lograrías obtener los resultados de la consulta pues antes de poder retornarlos ya estas cerrando la conexión y `$this->conexion` se volvería `NULL`

Entonces en este caso yo pensaría en los siguientes cambios:

1. *Quitar* la funcionalidad de cierre del método que ejecuta la query y dejar que haga lo que se supone debe que es consultar y devolver datos nadamás.
2. La conexión, en lugar de como la intentas establecer deberías mejor manejarlo a través de una estructura [`try/catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

   - En este mismo puento **considero** que debes hacer un return de la variable que tiene asignada la conexión para que en concencuencia puedas emplear el método para intentar la query
3. Entonces después cuando haces la instancia de la clase con ese objeto acceder al método de desconexión

Quedando mas o menos así así:

```
<?php 

class TuClase 
{

  /*
    Aqui tus propiedades
  */
  protected function conectar ()
  {
    try {
      /*
        Aqui tu conexión
      */
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
      /*
        Aqui atrapas la posible excepción
      */
    }

    return $this->conexion;
  }
  
  public function ejecutar($query)
  {
    //$this->conectar(); yo removería esto, no veo utilidad de que lo invoques aqui
    return mysqli_query($this->conectar(), $query);
  }

  protected function desconectar ()
  {
    mysqli_close($this->conectar());
  }
}


$tuObjetoInstanciado = new TuClase();
$tuObjetoInstanciado->ejecutar();
$tuObjetoInstanciado->desconectar();
```

**Nota**: Seguro el código tiene mucha oportunidad de mejora, pero de momento es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: aunque puede ayudar, creo que el problema es la configuracion de mysql

Answer (score 2):

De entrada, según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.mysqli.php) parece que en futuras versiones de PHP ya no se soportará `mysqli` en estilo por procedimientos y habrá que migrar a objetos.

Un error de lógica muy importante que tienes es que para cada consulta creas una conexión y eso no es necesario. Una sola conexión te permite ejecutar todas las consultas de una misma petición y, además, no es necesario cerrarla.

> [mysqli::close()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php)
> Las conexiones de MySQL no persistentes y los conjuntos de resultados **son automáticamente destruidos cuando un script de PHP finaliza su ejecución**. Por tanto, aunque el cierre explícito de conexiones abiertas y la liberación de conjuntos de resultados sean opcionales, se recomienda hacerlos. Así, se devolverán inmediatamente los recursos a PHP y a MySQL, lo que puede mejorar el rendimiento. Para información detalla, véase la liberación de recursos

En todo caso, para mejorar el rendimiento, lo que hay que liberar son los recursos de [juego de resultados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php).

Para simplificar un poco el proceso, te recomiendo definir constantes (en lugar de variables) para tener los parámetros que usarás al conectar a base de datos, **extender tu clase directamente de `mysqli`** y usar el [patrón Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) para tener siempre solo una conexión activa:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_BASE', 'test');

class Conexion extends mysqli {
  // Solo se permite una conexión
  private static $_instance = false;
  
  // No permitir instanciar con new Conexion
  private __constructor() {}

  // Devolver conexión a base de datos
  public static function conectar() {
    // Si aún no se ha establecido la conexión
    if(self::$_instance === false) {
      // Conectar
        self::$_instance = new self(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
        if (self::$_instance->connect_error) {
          die('Error de Conexión: (' . self::$_instance->connect_errno . ') ' . self::$_instance->connect_error);
        }
    }
    // Devuelve la conexión activa
    return self::$_instance;
  }
  // Este método realmente no es necesario, puedes usar query()
  public function ejecutar($query){
      // No es necesario asignar a otra variable, se puede devolver directamente
      return $this->query($query);
  }
}
```

**Nota:** Tu clase extiende de `mysqli` y, por tanto, tienes acceso a todos los métodos como query(), prepare(), close(), etc.

Cada que necesites acceso a base de datos:

```
<?php
// Incluir el archivo con la clase
require_once 'conexion.php';
// Obtener instancia de la clase y mantener solo una conexión
$db = Conexion::conectar();

// Ejecutar una consulta
$result = $db->ejecutar('SELECT * FROM tabla');
// Puede ser con el método query() de mysqli, para eso se extendió la clase
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tabla');
```

**Importante:** También va a cambiar la forma en que lees los [resultados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php), porque `$result` es un objeto y no puedes acceder con procedimientos como `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`, sino:

```
// Leer una sola fila
$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Ciclo para leer todas las filas
while($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($fila);
}
// Después de leer, si aún te preocupa, puedes liberar recursos
$result->free();
```

Aunque no es necesario (PHP lo hará por ti), al final de la petición es cuando puedes cerrar la conexión, solo asegúrate que no se van a ejecutar más consultas.

```
$db->close();
```

Finalmente, para mejorar la seguridad de tu proyecto y reducir el riesgo de errores, te recomiendo usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta tienes mi +1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya me quedo mucho mas claro y tomare las recomendaciones que me hiciste para hacer el desarrollo pensando en los cambios nuevos que se viene a php

Comment: ¿"*parece que en futuras versiones de PHP ya no se soportará mysqli en estilo por procedimientos*"? Para algunos la POO es novedad, mientras otros tantos proponen el regreso de la *Programación Funcional*. En medio de esas dos corrientes no veo en las rutas de camino de los desarrolladores de PHP la intención de inclinarse hacia algún estilo en particular. Si fuera así, ¿por qué hacer obsoleta la función `mysqli_execute()` en favor de la -**otra**- función `mysqli_stmt_execute()`?.